# Prove equality of norms of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $e_i$=${\{\delta_{k,i}}\}_{k\ge1}$ $\in$ $l_2$, $i\ge1$, $A_n$ and $B_n$ - operators that are defined like this:

$A_n\{x_i\}_{i\ge1}$ = $x_ne_1$, $B_n\{x_i\}_{i\ge1}$ = $x_1e_n$  $(\{x_i\}_{i\ge1} \in l_2)$

Prove that $||A_n|| = ||B_n||=1$, $A_n \rightarrow 0$, $B_n \rightarrow 0$ if $n \rightarrow \infty$

Can you suggest a brief plan to solve it and some hints, since I'm totally new to it. Thanks in advance

Comment: The type of convergence must be specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is an operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, the norm of $A$ is defined as
$$\|A\| := \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|. $$
So if $x\in\ell^2$ with $\|x\|=1$, then $$\|A_n x\|=\|x_n e_1\| \leqslant \|x_n\|\|e_1\|\leqslant 1, $$
which implies that $\|A\|\leqslant 1$. Since $A_n e_1 = e_1$ and $\|e_1\|=1$, indeed $\|A_n\|=1$. Computing the norm of $B_n$ follows an analogous argument.

If $x\in\ell^2$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2<\infty$ so $$\|A_n x\|=|x_n|^2\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0, $$
which implies that $A_n\rightharpoonup 0$. For each $n$, it is clear that $(B_n x)_k=0$ for $k\leqslant n$, and so $B_n\rightharpoonup 0$.

Comment: $\|A_nx\|\to 0$, for all $x$, DOES NOT imply that $A_n\to 0$. However, it implies that $A_nx\to 0$, for all $x$, i.e., $A_n\to 0$, weakly!

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis You are correct, it's been a couple years since I took operator theory :)

Answer (score 2):

Clearly,
$\|A_n\|=\|B_n\|=1$, since $\|A_n\|=\|B_n\|\le 1$ and $\|A_ne_n\|=1$, $\|B_ne_1\|=1$.

However, for every $x\in \ell_2$, 
$$
A_nx,\,B_nx\to 0,
$$
which means that $A_n,B_n\to 0$, *weakly*!